# Cómo calcular la cantidad de ceros en un data frame?

Tags: r

En el data frame "mi_df", las columnas 7 a 30 tienen valores aleatorios. Necesito calcular cuántas veces aparece el cero en cada FILA.
Quizás funciona algo como:

> mi_df$cant_ceros <- apply(mi.df[ ,7:30],1, ...)

pero no se como indicar que cuente la cantidad de ceros dentro de apply (matriz, 1, FUNCTION)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Agustina! Bienvenida a [es.so]. Aqui las preguntas han de mostrar lo intentado y el problema concreto que tienes, no la tarea a realizar. Por favor, editala y mejora la epxlicacion siguiendo [ask] y [mcve] . Un saludo !